# Auto clear text after 10 minutes

Tags: web

My website auto clear text in tag input html after 10 minutes. also I set idle timeout session 1 hour
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRJx.png)

Comment: Please share more details.

Answer (score 1):

IMO: I think you should use blazor for this if you are using MVC with Razor Pages or some js framework.
The server does not have to manage the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear the text in the HTML input after a certain time then you could try to use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function of JavaScript.

In the function, you could reset the input value.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>demo</title>
      <script>
         const myTimeout = setTimeout(clrval, 3000);
         
         function clrval() {
           document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";
         }
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>This is test page....</h1>
      <h2>Textbox value will be cleared after 3 seconds.</h2>
      Test Field : <input type="text" id="txt1" value="This is my sample text..."></br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if you have further questions.